# Equation to return 0 for "45" and 25 for "0" and whole numbers inbetween?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a number coming in from $0^{\circ}$ to $45^{\circ}$. When $0^{\circ}$ I need the number $25$. When $45^{\circ}$ I need the number $0$. In between can be whole numbers from $0$ to $25$.

If $0$ makes it difficult for division then $1$ will also work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the incoming number be $x$ then $$y=\left\lfloor 25 - {25\over45}x\right\rfloor$$ gives this result, where $\lfloor z\rfloor$ is the "floor" function.

Comment: Works perfect. I was talking to one of my buddies (we are both Java developers) and we are both disappointed to be math minors and unable to figure this out. Of course that was 15 years ago.